# How to identify the first response message to each previous message?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that contains messages from an agent and a customer.  I need to identify the first response from the agent to the customer, for each message sent by the customer and vice versa.

I have been trying to do this without success using the following query:

```
WITH HAVE AS
   (SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "CONSUMER" AS SENTBY, 1631929267942 AS TIMEL UNION ALL 
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929298918 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929307192 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "CONSUMER" AS SENTBY, 1631929313065 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929317717 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929333779 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "CONSUMER" AS SENTBY, 1631929337240 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929404611 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "CONSUMER" AS SENTBY, 1631929448033 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929477379 AS TIMEL
)

SELECT 
    CONVERSATIONID,
    SENTBY,
    TIMEL,
    CASE 
        WHEN FIRST_VALUE(TIMEL) OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERSATIONID, SENTBY ORDER BY TIMEL ASC) = TIMEL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS FIRST_MESSAGE,

FROM 
    HAVE

ORDER BY CONVERSATIONID, TIMEL
```

Is there a way to achieve the following result (where the red marks indicate that the value should be 1):

[image]

Any help would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(grp),
  if(
    row_number() over(partition by conversationid, grp order by timel) = 1
    and grp > 0, 1, 0
  ) first_message
from (
  select * except(isnew), 
    countif(isnew) over(partition by conversationid order by timel) grp
  from (
    select *,
      sentby != lag(sentby) over(partition by conversationid order by timel) isnew
    from have
  )
)
```

if apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: That is brilliant Mikhail.  One thing I don't understand is "AND GRP > 0, 1, 0".  How does that work?

Comment: logic behind this fragment (along with preceding row_numer line) is  - if row is the first one in the group but this is not the first group - assign 1 to this entry, otherwise assign 0

Comment: Also, is there a way to apply the TIMEL from the first record to the second record and the 4th  to the 5th and so on?

Comment: Regarding your explanation of the logic: That is perfect thank you.  I completely missed the IF.