# How to retain values from one message to the first reply to the message?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This question is an extension of [How to identify the first response message to each previous message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69444105/how-to-identify-the-first-response-message-to-each-previous-message), but given that it deals with different logic, I felt it best to raise another question.

This is the data that I now have thanks to @Mikhail:

[image]

This is the code used to generate the original data:

```
WITH HAVE AS
   (SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "CONSUMER" AS SENTBY, 1631929267942 AS TIMEL UNION ALL 
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929298918 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929307192 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "CONSUMER" AS SENTBY, 1631929313065 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929317717 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929333779 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "CONSUMER" AS SENTBY, 1631929337240 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929404611 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "CONSUMER" AS SENTBY, 1631929448033 AS TIMEL UNION ALL
    SELECT "A" AS CONVERSATIONID, "AGENT"    AS SENTBY, 1631929477379 AS TIMEL
)
```

Achieved using this code:

```
select * except(grp),
  if(
    row_number() over(partition by conversationid, grp order by timel) = 1
    and grp > 0, 1, 0
  ) first_message
from (
  select * except(isnew), 
    countif(isnew) over(partition by conversationid order by timel) grp
  from (
    select *,
      sentby != lag(sentby) over(partition by conversationid order by timel) isnew
    from have
  )
)
```

What I need to do now, is also get the value in TIMEL for the originating message and apply it to the first response. so in this scenario.  The Consumer asks a question at 1631929267942 (record 1) and the Agent responds at 1631929298918 (record 2).  The consumer could potentially as multiple questions before a reply from the Agent, but only the first of those questions should be used as the TIMEL value.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: not 100% clear. provide expected result to hopefully clarify expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query would replace the `TIMEL` value of the first response from the `AGENT` with that of the `CONSUMER` (i.e) the time at which the `CONSUMER` response originated.

```sql
select CONVERSATIONID, SENTBY, TIMEL,
    case when
    new_col > lag(new_col) over (partition by conversationid, grp order by timel) 
    then min(timel) over(partition by conversationid, grp order by timel)
    else timel 
    end as ORIGIN_TIMEL,
from(
    select * except(isnew), 
        countif(isnew) over(partition by conversationid order by timel) grp
    from (
        select *,
            new_col < lag(new_col) over(partition by conversationid order by timel) isnew
        from(
            select *,
            if(sentby = 'CONSUMER', 0, 1) new_col,
            from `project.dataset.table` 
            order by conversationid, timel
        )
    )
)
order by conversationid, timel
```

I've added a new row for `CONSUMER` to verify if the first `CONSUMER` response time is being used to replace the first `AGENT` response time.

**Output of the above query:**

[image]